# Three20 TabStrip

Tags: ios, three20, tabbar

I am using TabStrip on a project of mine. The tabstrip has TTTabItems that are the alphabet A-Z. When I click to each alphabet letter the delegate navigates to another page.

In the other page there is a TTTabstrip also (same construction, frame etc). How can I mark the alphabet also on the second tabstrip without triggering the event?

I tried to get the integer value of the letter mod the integer value of "a" (so that it will bring me an index) and assign it to selectedIndex:

```
unichar letter = [[NSString stringWithString:@"e"] characterAtIndex:0];
/*(k is @"a" unichar)*/
tabBar.selectedTabIndex = letter % kEnglishAlpha;
```

But it gives me deallocation error.

** UPDATE **

on the drill down detail view (where I have the problem) I mentioned in the comments I have the following coming from a tt navigation:

```
tt://listWords/Cat
```

on the view did load event, and after the initialization of the TTTabStrip (that contains only TTTabItem with letters A-Z) and the tabBar.delegate = self declaration, I use the upper code to "select" the chosen letter. The rest of the view shows the definition and everything related. Normally that would be the case, but when I use the back button to return to the view that has the tttableItems (cat, catsup, catnip etc) it says deallocated controller.

My guess is that using the tabselected delegation code and setting a tabindex, it triggers the  tab selected code immediate and that's where the problem is. If I don't use the selectedTabIndex code, I can navigate back and through the letters without problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's no function to auto selected a TTTabItem in TTStripTab.

You will have to extend TTTabStrip and add this function:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)setSelectedTabIndexToCenter:(NSInteger)selectedTabIndex {
  if (selectedTabIndex>_tabItems.count-1) {
    selectedTabIndex = _tabViews.count-1;
  }

  [self layoutSubviews];
  float horizontalOffset = 0.0f - _scrollView.size.width/2;
  for (int i = 0; i < selectedTabIndex; ++i) {
    TTTab* tab = [_tabViews objectAtIndex:i];
      if (selectedTabIndex-1==i) {
        horizontalOffset += tab.size.width*1.5;

      } else {
          horizontalOffset += tab.size.width;
      }
    }
    if (horizontalOffset<0) {
      horizontalOffset = 0;
    }

    _scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(horizontalOffset, 0);
    [super setSelectedTabIndex:selectedTabIndex];
}
```

This function will select a specific tab item and center on it by changing the offset of the strip tab.

Comment: Thanks for that one, but will changing the selectedTabIndex fire the tabselected event? Because that is what my problem is, it fires it up and somehow it deallocates the whole controller. My app is a drill down using tabstrip. I have the first viewcontroller (search & tab) someone presses the item, then the item on the second viewcontroller presents the data and a third viewcontroller presents the details. On the second viewcontroller indeed I have the letter selected, but on the third one if I select the letter (programmatically, to show it's on the letter C for example) it does dealloc.

Comment: sorry, i thought you meant something else. can you post the code of the controller?